# Using Java to automate google and print output

Tags: java, arrays, search-engine

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to implement this:

I have an array of strings (~650 elements) and would like to google each element, and then have the number of results acquired in each search stored in another integer array. I looked at the Google API, but it seems a little daunting to me, it seems like a fairly simple task, but can't seem to find any guidance on how to do this.

Help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to do the following. I don't think its the fastest or most elegant way, but I think it should do the trick:

If you check a URL on Google, they all look the same:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q='here your searchword'
```

So i would just iterate over your array and for each string create a url like e.g.

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=test
```

do a HTTP-Post for that and parse the result.

[Here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html) is a short example of the HTTPPost. You can also see how to get the response. I don't know how googles response is looking, but if you just print out the whole response, I think you will see how you have to parse it.

Comment: I was considering that, but I thought that would just involve a lot of copying and pasting.

How would I go abbout a HTTP-Post/Parse?
I was also joping for a more elegant way of just returning the number of results into each element of another array.

Comment: Thanks again. When I try to create a new URL, it tells me that URL cannot be resolved to a type, how/where i can I import this class?

Comment: You have to import java.net.URL

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html